# A char array of 64x64 get overwritten constantily. STM32F407 Keil Arm

Tags: arrays, overrun

The program has 2 extern arrays of 64X64. One works fine the other most of time has values changed persistently.

I already try to declare the arrays as volatile and did not make a difference. I suspect that is necessary to place those arrays in a fixed interval of memory but I do not have that much knowledge to do this. Likely if the array were declared as static would work but I really need the arrays as extern for USB communication.
I also try to increase the Heap and Stack without any luck.

Please, is there any good soul to help with this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.